# two titlegraphics

Tags: titles

In my LaTeX document (`report`) I would like to insert two graphics on top of the title page. 
Here is a code which already worked in a `beamer` document:

```
\titlegraphic{\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{pictures/pic1.jpg}%
    \end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}%
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{pictures/pic2.jpg}%
    \end{figure}
\end{column}\end{columns}}
```

In `\documentclass{report}` 14 errors are returned.
The first one is

```
undefined control sequence \titlegraphic
{\begin{columns}
LaTeX Error: Environment columns undefined`.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`beamer`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beamer) class defines the `columns` and `column` environments, which are really just like the `minipage` environment, except that they know all about `beamer`s clever tricks; they are *overlay aware*.

The other document classes don't know about the `columns` or `column` environment unless you tell them. A simple fix would be to load the [`titlepic`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/titlepic) package, for example, and then use something like the following code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Graphics in report}
\author{me}
\begin{document}


%\titlegraphic{\begin{columns} <!-- old
\titlepic{%\begin{columns} %    <!-- new
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        %\begin{figure}%            <!-- new
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
        %\end{figure}               <!-- new
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        %\begin{figure}%
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
        %\end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    %\end{columns}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

You'll want to change the images back to the ones you were using before :)

Answer (score 2):

A "quick'n dirty" method without loading additional packages could be the direct use of `\includegraphics` inside `\title{}`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{image-a} \\
Fancy title \\
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{image-b} 
}
\author{Someone}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Text

\end{document}
```

Works also fine together with `\minipage{}` if you need to group them side by side.